# How to avoid matlab splash screen while running matlab engine

Tags: matlab-engine

You could avoid matlab splash screen in normal launch by editing the matlab.desktop file with arguments matlab -nosplash. This is how you do the same when you open matlab engine from C/C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
engOpen("matlab -nosplash")
```

While opening the matlab engine, give the above arguments.

Comment: Yes, however this works on OS X and Linux only.  On Windows the required usage is `engOpen(NULL)`.